# HMTL template not showing in Flask

Tags: html, flask

I'm trying to build a website for a family friend using Flask framework. However, when I'm mapping out the url routing for each HTML template, I'm getting a 404 error, saying the url was not found on the server. I'm adding in a snippet of code to see if it helps me get an answer.

```
@app.route("/instructors.html")
def instructors():
    return render_template("/instructors.html")

@app.route("/classes.html")
def classes():
    return render_template("/classes.html")
```

Comment: @PatrickYoder well you can look over the code (minus todays updates) in the repo github.com/Brogrammerdude and it's in the flask-site repo

Comment: @PatrickYoder I've found the culprit. i had shitty directory structure. super palm to the face. plus, i also didn't have the proper flask syntax for the nav-bar hrefs. i needed to write it as "href={{url_for('classes')}}" and i had missed that part

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `.html` from your routes:

```
@app.route("/instructors")
def instructors():
    return render_template("/instructors.html")

@app.route("/classes")
def classes():
    return render_template("/classes.html")
```

Comment: Still isn't rendering the templates. And just for the hell of it, i copied the exact path of the templates and added them in to see if that would work. Still nothing. I'm pouring through the Flask docs and I seem to be doing everything according to the docs....yet still here banging my head on the desk lol

Comment: OK I've reproduced it here and it works. Are you sure your templates folder is called `templates`? all lowercase, no trailing space?

Comment: What error do you see? Are you running in development mode? Debug=True?

Comment: yes, the folder is called templates, all lowercase, no trailing space. i'm not running in dev mode, no. the error is exactly this: "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."